# How to force restart pod when there is change in container environment variable

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

i am trying to deploy image which has some change to it environment variables, but when i do so i am getting below error

> The Pod "envar-demo" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not
>   change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`,
>   `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or
>   `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations)
>   {"Volumes":[{"Name":"default-token-9dgzr","HostPath":null,"EmptyDir":null,"GCEPersistentDisk":null,"AWSElasticBlockStore":null,"GitRepo":null,"Secret":{"SecretName":"default-token-9dgzr","Items":null,"DefaultMode":420,"Optional":null},"NFS":null,"ISCSI":null,"Glusterfs":null,"PersistentVolumeClaim":null,"RBD":null,"Quobyte":null,"FlexVolume":null,"Cinder":null,"CephFS":null,"Flocker":null,"DownwardAPI":null,"FC":null,"AzureFile":null,"ConfigMap":null,"VsphereVolume":null,"AzureDisk":null,"PhotonPersistentDisk":null,"Projected":null,"PortworxVolume":null,"ScaleIO":null,"StorageOS":null}],"InitContainers":null,"Containers":[{"Name":"envar-demo-container","Image":"gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0","Command":null,"Args":null,"WorkingDir":"","Ports":null,"EnvFrom":null,"Env":[{"Name":"DEMO_GREETING","Value":"Hello
>   from the environment

my yaml.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars-new
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment-change value"
    - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
      value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
```

why i am not able to deploy, when there is change to my container environment variables.

my pod is running state, but still i need to change my environment variable, and restart my pod.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually, you are better off using deployments for this use case.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: node-hello
  labels:
    app: node-hello
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: node-hello
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: node-hello
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: DEMO_GREETING
          value: "Hello from the environment-change value"
        - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
          value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
```

this way you would be able to change environment variables and the pod will get restarted with the new environment variables

Comment: It's probably worth noting that, in order to restart the pod with the new variables, we need to apply it: `kubectl apply -f  myfile.yaml`

Comment: because its not a pod, its a higher level abstraction

Comment: You _can’t_ change these fields in an existing Pod.  If you create a Deployment, it will take responsibility for destroying and creating Pods as the Deployment spec changes.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of requirements,  a `replicaset` or a `Deployment`(prefered) can be used.

You may also try to read the ENV value from outside, if there is change, you(i.e. a `script` or `job` or `scheduler`) can restart a new Pod with the new ENV values.